# process.env, global var, warning "plugin svelte: 'X' is not defined", plugin-replace

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollupjs, svelte-3

I'm using this in `rollup.config.js`:

```js
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
...
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
...
replace({
  IS_PRODUCTION: isProd,
}),
```

and in my Svelte code like this ():

```
{#if !IS_PRODUCTION && failure}
  <p>{failure}</p>
{/if}
```

It works!

But I get an annoying warning in console during compilation:

```
(!) Plugin svelte: 'IS_PRODUCTION' is not defined
src\Router.svelte
101: {/if}
102:
103: {#if !IS_PRODUCTION && failure}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using Sapper?

Comment: Nope. I fixed it with rollup-plugin-replace.

Comment: order of rollup plugin ? like svelte compiles the component before the replace plugin is running ?